# SQLite check if at max id

Tags: sql, apache-flex, sqlite, actionscript

I'm using SQLite to store data for a small mobile app.  When the user presses the 'next' button, I would like data to be loaded from the next record.  I have that part done, but how do I check and see if the next record is the last (max) one?  And if it is, is it as simple as setting the id = 0 to start at the beginning?

**My Current 'next'():**

```
private function nextMoveRPart(event:EffectEvent):void
{
    var cardNumber:int = parseInt(cardNumberLabel.text);

    stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
    conn.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("FlashCards.db"));
    stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cardItems IF id <= MAX(id)" + "AND id <= MAX(id) WHEN id = ?";
    stmt.parameters[0] = cardNumber+1;
    stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandlerPrev);
    stmt.execute();
    conn.close();
    moveEffectRPart2.play();
}
```

**resultHandlerNext()**

```
function resultHandlerNext(event:SQLEvent):void  // result handler next
{
    var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
    var numResults:int = result.data.length;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++)
    {
        var row:Object = result.data[i];
        stext1.text = row.cSide1;
        stext2.text = row.cSide2;
        cardNumberLabel.text = row.id;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to say without the definition, but essentially, to get the next record and wrap around, I would proceed this way.

First, count if there is at least one more record to go.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cardItems WHERE id > ?
```

If the count result is at least 1, fetch that result:

```
SELECT * FROM cardItems WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

If the count result was 0, rollback:

```
SELECT * FROM cardItems WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM cardItems)
```

This takes care of several cases. For example, if your id's are not always "current+1" (say you have a deleted record), and if your first id isn't 0.